# All data is not being populate from linkedin when login in django app

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api

i want to login with linkedin in m y django app
I am using ouath2 and django version 1.8
i want to populate all basic information like industry,email id,profile picture,designation.
I can populate only 3 details first_name , last_name, id.
I am using extra data to populate more data but its not working.
My **settings.py** is

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # 'registration_email.auth.EmailBackend'
    # 'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['picture-url', 'email-address', 'headline', 'industry']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'id'),
                       ('first-name', 'first_name'),
                       ('last-name', 'last_name'),
                       ('email-address', 'email_address'),
                       ('headline', 'headline'),
                       ('industry', 'industry')]


SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = '1234561324565'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = '123d132wew13w'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'
```

Data which i can populate

```
{"access_token": "AQV2xtQellmn9BHcfSVaFmxHcp0QWORWvH3iW6TquiYm9mzhRuBPJLwM62YsIanQKdNh_wsqIRMHg-1lh7SU__4n4jo4V0UUaRIqeHom3ndyw0tpeS5sBMRSf3FPJeFqCTP-_axpGi2SlsLK2RWu4IfMRLvb8Bk1ni9dR1XUqbozeyS028U", "first_name": "chandra prakash", "last_name": "verma", "id": "ASvzLdVgAl"}
```

Please help me how can i populate all the data

Comment: have you looked into 'Default Application Permissions' for your app under 'My Apps' https://developer.linkedin.com ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  Im having the same issue